# Access to user credentials in ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET core (2.1), running on a windows, I am using HttpSys configured with the following authentication schemes:

```
builder.UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
        })
```

Then in my Startup.Configure() method I am attempting to access the user credentials of the client calling the uri "/sensitiveOperation" as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Equals("/sensitiveOperation") && context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethods.Put), subApp =>
        {                
            subApp.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                if (context.User.Identity.Name == "admin")
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Performing sensitive operation.");
                    // .. Do Sensitive operation....
                }                    
            });
        });
```

The example is slightly vulgarised, but the main point is that context.User.Identity.Name is always empty where I would expect to see the name of the AD account which is making the call. Note that the call is done in powershell as follows:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:5555/sensitiveOperation -Method Put -UseDefaultCredentials
```

I could put this code in a controller and use the [Authorize] attribute to get the credentials but I would prefer to do this operation before hitting the Mvc pipeline. Is there any way to get the user at this early stage of the pipeline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would not want to set `AllowAnonymous` as `false`, you could try `context.ChallengeAsync` to authenticate the request based on `Credential`.

Here are the code:

```
        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Equals("/sensitiveOperation") && context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethods.Put), subApp =>
        {
            subApp.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var authService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();

                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    //await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows"); //Option1
                    //await context.ChallengeAsync();  //Option2
                    await context.ChallengeAsync(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); //Option3
                }
                if (context.User.Identity.Name == "admin")
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Performing sensitive operation.");
                    // .. Do Sensitive operation....
                }
            });
        });
```

**Note**, for this way, `subApp.Run` will run twice, first request is UnAuthenticated, and it will challenge the credentail, second request is Authenticated and `context.User.Identity.Name` will have value. This process is back-end, this would not be reflected in `powershell`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for as I indeed need to allow anonymous for certain routes.

Answer (score 5):

Change AllowAnonymous

```
options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
```

If you have anonymous on, and you're not prompting for authentication then the browser isn't going to authenticate. Even if you do send creates asp.net isn't going to get them unless there's an Authenticate attribute on the controller/method or, if you're going the function route, you call signin.

Answer (score 3):

I am using .NET Core 3.0 and in my custom middleware I was able to get the UserId with this code:

```
httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
    ? new Guid(httpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).First().Value)
    : Guid.Empty
```